# jCrop not updating text fields, Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jcrop

I have an app where I have two different jCrops working (user images and group images). The user one works fine and the group one is exactly like it except for the appropriate change in the div names. jCrop is not updating the text fields so the image is not cropped properly. The preview does update properly, so the coffee script is getting loaded and the issue is with the update coods. I'm not getting any errors in dev tools either.

**Crop Page**

```
 <div class="col-md-7">
        <%= image_tag @group.image_url, id: "cropbox" %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <h4>Preview</h4>
    <div class="jcrop" style="width:100px; height:100px; overflow:hidden; border-radius: 50px;">
        <%= image_tag @group.image_url, :id => "preview" %>
        </div>
    <%= form_for @group do |f| %>
        <% %w[x y w h].each do |attribute| %>
            <%= f.text_field "crop_#{attribute}" %>
        <% end %>
        <div class="actions m-t-md">
        <%= f.button "Crop Image", class: "btn btn-primary mt10", data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-fw fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Cropping"} %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**Groups.coffee**

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/

jQuery ->
  new AvatarCropper()
class AvatarCropper
  constructor: ->
    $('#cropbox').Jcrop
      aspectRatio: 1
      setSelect: [0, 0, 500, 500]
      onSelect: @update
      onChange: @update

  update: (coords) =>
    $('#group_crop_x').val(coords.x)
    $('#group_crop_y').val(coords.y)
    $('#group_crop_w').val(coords.w)
    $('#group_crop_h').val(coords.h)
    @updatePreview(coords)

  updatePreview: (coords) =>
    $('#preview').css
      width: Math.round(100/coords.w * $('#cropbox').width()) + 'px'
      height: Math.round(100/coords.h * $('#cropbox').height()) + 'px'
      marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(100/coords.w * coords.x) + 'px'
      marginTop: '-' + Math.round(100/coords.h * coords.y) + 'px'
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. A clue was in the second sentence of my question. I had two methods with the same name. Obviously this will not work. Changing the method names, and the div names, cleared up all the issues.